# menu's go down when zoomed-out in browser

Tags: css

I am doing a website project on asp.net 3.5. When i Zoom-out the interface on web-browser my menu bar's Contact tab goes below also the places to visit tab's line "visit" comes below. How can I overcome this problem?

### HTML

```
 <div id="nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="Default.aspx">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Reservation</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="Availability.aspx">Room</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Membership</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>

                        </ul>
                     </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Places to visit</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Travel</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Packages</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Contact.aspx">Contact us</a></li>
                </ul>
           </div>
```

### CSS

```css
#nav { clear:both; margin:0;
            padding:0;width:900px; height:30px;}

#nav ul { margin:0; padding:0; line-height:30px; }
#nav li { margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none; float:left;
                position:relative;
                background-color:#0066CC/*#1B6187*/;}


#nav ul li a { text-align:center;
                    font-family:Georgia;
                    text-decoration:none;
                    font-size:14px;
                    height:30px; display:block;
                    color:#FFF; width:110.5px;
                     border:1px solid #006363;
                     }
#nav ul ul { position:absolute; visibility:hidden; top:32px;}
#nav ul li:hover ul {visibility:visible;}

#nav li:hover { background:#09F;}
#nav ul li:hover ul li a:hover {background-color:#09F;
                color:#4EE6DB;}
#nav ul li ul li { background-color:#0066CC/*#1B6187*/;}

#nav a:hover { color:#000;}

.clearFloat {clear:both;}
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the text doesn't scale well when zooming: it stays bigger than you'd expect. The text forces the surrounding li's and a's to get bigger than you'd like.

I recently fixed the same issue by fixing the width of each li (eg: width: 30px). The text will still be bigger than you'd like, but if you use enough padding it has enough space to grow.

What you could also try is position the last li absolutely top top:0, right:0, this will get ugly as the last li will lay over the one before the last